# How to compare a variable to member variables of objects contained in a vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a vector `std::vector<StudentGradeInfo> gradebook;` objects of the class `StudentGradeInfo`. The `StudentGradeInfo` class contains the following member variables:
`std::string studentName;
 int studentID;
 std::string major;`

What I need to do is overload the == operator to compare the `ID` input from the user and compare it to the `studentID` member variables of the objects in the vector `std::vector<StudentGradeInfo> gradebook;`.

How would I go about looping through the vector to compare the ID's? It would probably be a non-member function since it is comparing an int variable to a member function of an object, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: You want to look up the `StudentGradeInfo`-object with a particular `studentID` within the vector, right?

Comment: @StephanLechner yeah I think. I want to make sure that the user input `ID` is not the same as any `studentID`s in the vector already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do it like this if you absolutely have to make an overloaded `operator==`.

```
bool operator==(const StudentGradeInfo& sgi, int id) {
    return sgi.studentID == id; 
}

std::vector<StudentGradeInfo> gradebook;
int id_to_find=1234;

for(auto& sgi : gradebook) {
    if(sgi==id_to_find) {
        //...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to loop through the vector to find a studentGrandeInfo-object with a particular ID. You can accomplish this rather easy by using `std::find_if` together with a lambda-function for the proper comparison. The code could look as follows:

```
int toFind = 4219; // some ID
auto it = std::find_if(
gradebook.begin(), gradebook.end(),
[&toFind](const StudentGradeInfo& x) { return x.studentID == toFind;});
```

In your case, as you the `studentID` seems to serve as a "unique key", I'd use data structure `std::map<int, StrudentGradeInfo>` instead.

Overloading operator `==` is - as gsamars pointed out - somehow impractical, as it is meant for comparing two objects of the same type (and not an object with an int). See the following code illustrating this:

```
struct StudentGradeInfo {
    std::string studentName;
    int studentID;

    bool operator==(const StudentGradeInfo& c) const {
        return c.studentID == studentID;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::vector<StudentGradeInfo> gradebook {
        { "john", 123 },
        { "max", 345 }
    };

    StudentGradeInfo aNewOne { "sepp", 345 };
    auto it = find(gradebook.begin(),gradebook.end(),aNewOne);
    if (it == gradebook.end()) {
        cout << "345 does not exist" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "345 already exists" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought! Wondering why the OP said he needs an operator overloading...

Comment: I wish I could use this solution @gsamaras , but the problem I am working on requires an overloaded operator ==. Thank you for the quick answer however.

Comment: That means that you have to create another object of your class @throwthedays with the ID the user gave! Are you sure this is what you want? The `operator==` compares can compare two classes.